# Spring AOP: How to read path variable value from URI template in aspect?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to create Spring aspect which would set method parameter, annotated by custom annotation, to an instance of a particular class identified by an id from URI template. Path variable name is parameter of the annotation. Very similar to what Spring `@PathVariable` does.

So that controller method would look like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/testController")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/order/{orderId}/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> doSomething(
            @GetOrder("orderId") Order order) {

        // do something with order
    }

}
```

Instead of classic:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/testController")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/order/{orderId}/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> doSomething(
            @PathVariable("orderId") Long orderId) {

        Order order = orderRepository.findById(orderId);
        // do something with order
    }
}
```

Annotation source:

```
// Annotation
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface GetOrder{

    String value() default "";
}
```

Aspect source:

```
// Aspect controlled by the annotation
@Aspect
@Component
public class GetOrderAspect {

    @Around( // Assume the setOrder method is called around controller method )
    public Object setOrder(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable{

        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) jp.getSignature();
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class[] types = signature.getParameterTypes();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();
        Annotation[][] annotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
        Object[] values = jp.getArgs();

        for (int parameter = 0; parameter < types.length; parameter++) {
            Annotation[] parameterAnnotations = annotations[parameter];
            if (parameterAnnotations == null) continue;

            for (Annotation annotation: parameterAnnotations) {
                // Annotation is instance of @GetOrder
                if (annotation instanceof GetOrder) {
                    String pathVariable = (GetOrder)annotation.value();                        

                    // How to read actual path variable value from URI template?
                    // In this example case {orderId} from /testController/order/{orderId}/delete

                    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder
                            .currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
                    ????? // Now what?

                }
           } // for each annotation
        } // for each parameter
        return jp.proceed();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 04/Apr/2017:**

Answer given by [Mike Wojtyna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183537/spring-aop-how-to-read-path-variable-value-from-uri-template-in-aspect/43185546#43185546) answers the question -> thus it is accepted.

Answer given by [OrangeDog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183537/spring-aop-how-to-read-path-variable-value-from-uri-template-in-aspect/43185007#43185007) solves the problem form different perspective with existing Spring tools without risking implementation issue with new aspect. If I knew it before, this question would not be asked.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you have a look at the source for how `@PathVariable` is used?

Comment: No I did not, honestly I do not know where to start, it is quite obscure.

Comment: As an aside, you should be using an @DeleteMapping with a delete verb against a url of `/order/{orderId}`, not a 'get' with a `/order/{orderId}/delete` url. Also, IDs are usually better as uuids, rather than numbers. Further, isn't loading a resource before you delete it a waste of computing resources, given that in most backing stores you can issue a `delete by key` type command.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't spot that. If you use GETs for state-changing operations you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: It is just an example, simplified real problem, nothing more.Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already have access to `HttpServletRequest`, you can use `HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE` spring template to select map of all attributes in the request. You can use it like that:

```
request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE)
```

The result is a `Map` instance (unfortunately you need to cast to it), so you can iterate over it and get all the parameters you need.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this sort of thing is with `@ModelAttribute`, which can go in a `@ControllerAdvice` to be shared between multiple controllers.

```
@ModelAttribute("order")
public Order getOrder(@PathVariable("orderId") String orderId) {
    return orderRepository.findById(orderId);
}

@DeleteMapping("/order/{orderId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> doSomething(@ModelAttribute("order") Order order) {
    // do something with order
}
```

Another way is to implement your own `PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver` that supports `Order`, or register a `Converter<String, Order>`, that the existing `@PathVariable` system can use.

Comment: Your approach solves the problem form different, more elegant perspective. Thank you!

Comment: How can get pathVariable above of function in custom annotation? I ask in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60297081)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it is always the first parameter bearing the annotation, maybe you want to do it like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import de.scrum_master.app.GetOrder;

@Aspect
@Component
public class GetOrderAspect {
  @Around("execution(* *(@de.scrum_master.app.GetOrder (*), ..))")
  public Object setOrder(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) thisJoinPoint.getSignature();
    Annotation[][] annotationMatrix = methodSignature.getMethod().getParameterAnnotations();
    for (Annotation[] annotations : annotationMatrix) {
      for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
        if (annotation instanceof GetOrder) {
          System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
          System.out.println("  annotation = " + annotation);
          System.out.println("  annotation value = " + ((GetOrder) annotation).value());
        }
      }
    }
    return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
  }
}
```

The console log would look like this:

```
execution(ResponseEntity de.scrum_master.app.TestController.doSomething(Order))
  annotation = @de.scrum_master.app.GetOrder(value=orderId)
  annotation value = orderId
```

If parameter annotations can appear in arbitrary positions you can also use the pointcut `execution(* *(..))` but this would not be very efficient because it would capture all method executions for each component in your application. So you should at least limit it to REST controlers and/or methods with request mappings like this:

```java
@Around("execution(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping * (@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *).*(..))")
```

A variant of this would be

```java
@Around(
  "execution(* (@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *).*(..)) &&" +
  "@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)"
)
```

Comment: I do not want to get value of `@GetOrder` annotation, but value of path variable identified by the `@GetOrder`.

Comment: But you need the annotation value in order to take the next step. I solved the corresponding Spring AOP problem for you (your code did not even compile in my IDE). I am an AOP expert and found the question because it is tagged with `spring-aop`, but not a Spring user. So this is the part I could do for you. The Spring part you have to solve by yourself. Maybe next time you ask two separate questions to find an expert for each.

Comment: Actually getting annotation value is solved the in the example `String pathVariable = (GetOrder)annotation.value();`

Comment: No, this snippet is exactly what does not compile, it has to be `((GetOrder) annotation).value()` ;-) Furthermore, it should be `if (annotation instanceof GetOrder)` instead of `if (annotation instanceof GetProfile)`.

Comment: Right, it was a copy/paste problem. I am sorry if it misled you.